# JQuery works without text processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, templates

please, help me with the next issue:
I have some html-templates on the page for javascript-rendering in  element and load this content in the js variable. Then i want to find concrete div with id in that text, but there is a problem - in template i have `<img src={{=url}}>` and that throw console error when i try to append that text to the JQuery object, how can i find desired element with JQuery without loading images?

I want to keep `src="{{=image}}"` without loading real image, but JQuery not allow me

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us some code ..!!

Comment: i dont see problem with template

Comment: there is a part of code snippet :  <div class="span4">
                    <img src="{{= image }}" alt="" class="addwidgettemplateimage">
                </div> And i want to find it in string variable without loading image with not valid src via JQuery selectors, so let me simplify : i want to processing string using JQuery

Comment: Cannot figure out your exact problem, please give a more clear explanation  !

Comment: Do you want the src attribute of the <img> tag ?

Comment: I want to keep src="{{=image}}" without loading real image, but JQuery not allow me

Comment: But where do you want to keep src="{{=image}}", this as a text inside some div ?

Comment: You're allowed to keep whatever you want, as long as it's only a string.  I'm guessing the issue you're having is when you put that string into the DOM.  It's not jQuery that's not allowing you to do so; it's the basic rules of HTML.  You're using invalid syntax.  At the very least, make `src="{{=image}}"`.  In your question, you don't have the `"` marks.  Still, when you add that to the DOM, your browser is required to automatically try and load the image.

Comment: Okay, that is useful for me, but can you clarify me some simple way to cut concrete dom element from plain string via javascript?

Comment: [upd] I think the some regexp could help me